# SSRS Multiple Datasets from different data sources into one table with grouping causing duplicate rows

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate, grouping

SSRS report needs to have aggregate and grouping from two data sets. I have managed to get this working using the lookup funcion. Looks like it is now duplicating the rows when I only want it to show the top row.

I have two groups. Active and Stanby[image]. Each has different values in it but the same value per row.

I tried to hide duplicates under properties, but that now keeps the first row and the border of all other rows with an empty field inside of it.

The hide visibility doesnt seem to work - i think it might be because of the grouping.

Can someone help?

See attached image

Comment: In your table dataset, join the two other datasets then select distinct.

Comment: I can't join the datasets, they are on two different servers

Comment: No linked servers or replication in place. That's why I used the lookup function in SSRS which worked. Now causing duplicate rows possibly the grouping

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31414.ssrs-merge-data-from-different-datasources-into-one-dataset-inside-ssrs-report.aspx

Comment: Can't you **Group** the detail lines by the expressions for the **Channel Count**, **Count Endpoints**, and **DDI Sum**?

Comment: Thats what I did

Comment: E.g sum(field!channelcount.value),"groups")